# handle tap event in the whole content page out of certain element

Tags: xamarin.forms

after i finished slide down menu (which is a stacklayout containing buttons) on button click on my Pcl i am trying to hide this menu when the user taps any part of the page out of my menu 
i used TapGestureRecongnizer and added it to content but it doesnot work on other children elements

```
        TapGestureRecognizer ContentGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        ContentGesture.Tapped +=(s,o)=>{

            if (CornerFrame.IsVisible == true)
            { CornerFrame.IsVisible = false; }

                };
        this.Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(ContentGesture);
```

Comment: Add your code how to show stacklayout ?

Comment: AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(CornerFrame, new Rectangle(1, 0, 0.3, 0.3));
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(CornerFrame, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            AbsLayout.Children.Add(CornerFrame);MenuBarBtn.Clicked += (s, o) =>
            {
            CornerFrame.IsVisible = true;
            Content.FadeTo(0.8);
                CornerFrame.FadeTo(1);
            };    CornerFrame.Content = UpCornerStack; i just set visible to true

Comment: CornerFrame is your stacklayout right?

Comment: yes it is normal Frame containing stacklayout , yes its

Comment: Try my answer hope its help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Below code in your stack layout page

```
public event EventHandler<bool> ItemChanged;
TapGestureRecognizer ContentGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        ContentGesture.Tapped +=(s,o)=>{

           ItemChanged?.Invoke(this, true);

                };
        this.Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(ContentGesture);
```

Below code in your main page where you add CornerFrame in page

```
CornerFrame.ItemChanged += (object sender, bool arg) =>
{
     if (CornerFrame.IsVisible == true)
            { CornerFrame.IsVisible = false; }
};
```

Comment: ok i am working on it i am just trying to define the event handler because  i am not able to access it on the page, but still gives me CornerFrame doesnot contain a definition for ItemChanged

Comment: in the first code snippet but not working in the second snippet it gives me CornerFrame doesnot have a definition for ItemChanged

Comment: Try this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38141/custom-controls-and-eventhandler